# Append HTML to Routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a basic `index.html` file that when a requested by the browser the routes file will add / append a html button to that file but wont actually write to the file. It sounds silly but I want todo this so that I can dynamically add "mini apps"  for certain users that view a dashboard.

Comment: Where's the question that describes where you got stuck in solving this yourself?  What solutions have you researched and tried?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to make a static code dynamic without actual dynamic code on the server (which would be parsing the html on every request and putting a button in it which is very expensive on the processor). I suggest that you use javascript to place this button since your question does not offer any code to be improved on.

If you are open to templates, it's your lucky day. ExpressJS supports templates really well:
http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html

Alternatively you can place tags such as <% button here %> and use `.replace` or RegEX to replace from a buffer or string of that specific file.

Edit:

Example for the last suggestion. This code is incomplete and **please don't use this in production**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(path_to_file, { encoding: 'utf8' }, function(error, buffer){
      if(error) return res.status(404).end();
      res.send(buffer.replace('<% tag %>', "<div ...>"));
  });
});
```